# Javascript best practice to check only null values

Tags: javascript, null

I want to check the null value in JavaScript.

For instance, test() is function which could return null. So If I want to test the null check efficiently what should be my approach.

```
var a = test();
```

followed by

```
if (a) {}
```

OR

```
if (a !== null) {}
```

?
since **if (a)** will check for null, undefined, false, 0, NaN which might not be the best approach when we know we could get only null value.

Comment: `If I want to test the null check efficiently`, is that the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: `I want to check the null value`. So check the null value: `if (a !== null) {}`?

Comment: if you don't check for strict equality with the value null, you will be checking for all false-y values. so you must use 'if (a === null){...}'. FYI, null is not the same as undefined (or 0, or false, or "").

Comment: Yeah, my question is basically about the efficiency, whether using a !== null ,a better approach ? or it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Many years late but @adrichman's comment above is misleading. You do not need a *strict* equality; loose equality would be sufficient unless you specifically want to rule out `undefined`. `false == null`, `0 == null`, `-0 == null`, `0n == null`, `NaN == null`, `"" == null` are all false. `undefined == null` and `null == null` are true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check null only

```
if (value !== null) {
}
```

If you want to check even for 'undefined'

```
if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null)
```

I will recommend you to check both `undefined` and `null` value.

```
function test() {
  var a;
  return a;  // returns undefined
}

function test() {
  var a = null;
  return a;  // returns null   
}
```

So there is a possibility that value can `undefined` or `null`. So better to check both.

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed out, different methods check for different things and you need to choose the most suitable one depending on your needs. The differences in performance between them are minuscule and certainly not worth micro-optimizing against.

---

**`if (a)`**

Ensures a truthy value. This might not be what you wanted if a return value of `0` or `''` is actually valid.

---

**`if (a !== null)`**

Ensures a null returned value is filtered.

---

**`if (a !== null && a !== undefined)`**

Ensures a null or undefined value is filtered.

---

**`if (a != null)`**

Same as the previous one, filters out null and undefined values. It is shorter, but certain coding styles enforce strict equality checks and a careless maintainer could inadvertendly change the logic by "fixing" it.

---

**`var a = test() || default;`**

Not exactly a check, but very useful because it doesn't branch your logic. When a certain default value can be applied if the result of the test() call is falsy, you might want to use this to avoid the if alltogether and have a clear code path.